Find the top left cell in a table in the middle of a spreadsheet
The code below works as written.  The issue is that it does not return the correct number of columns.  Cell A1 has data, but none of the rest of the cells in row A have data, so the range defined is only one column wide.  I think I need to replace the "1" in the line that says:  LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column with something that identifies the first row of the table that has all the columns.  I don't know how to do that. The top left cell of the table is "User- User Full Name"
Appreciate your help
Sub Range_Variable_Example()

  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim LR As Long 'LR = Last Row for Understanding
  Dim LC As Long 'LC = Last Column for Understanding
  
    Worksheets("Home").Select
    
  LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

  Set Rng = Cells(1, 1).Resize(LR, LC)

  Rng.Select


Use Set origin = Cells.Find("User- User Full Name")

Then you can use .CurrentRegion to identify the whole table.

What do you mean by "the cells in row A"? It's either in row 1 or in column A. If it's row 1 then I can't see how row 1 is part of the data. Please clarify (is there a title and headers in the first 2 rows?). Best add a screenshot to you post.

The way of row and column calculation has nothing to do with your mentioned table. This way of calculation is related to data in A:A (for number of rows) and it assumes that there are headers (or other kind of data) in the first row. Besides showing a non working piece of code (according to your need), please better explain (in words) what you try accomplishing. Anyhow, if there is also data below the table in discussion) and you need to determine the last cell/row in the table  you need to change the way of calculation.

If the "table" you're referring to is a formatted Table, then it's accessible via the ListObjects collection.
Sub printTableRanges()

Dim listObject1 As ListObject
Dim headerAndDataBodyRange As Range

Set listObject1 = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)

Debug.Print listObject1.Range.Address
Debug.Print listObject1.HeaderRowRange.Address
Debug.Print listObject1.DataBodyRange.Address

End Sub

If you're not able to format the range as a Table, then use any combination of Range.End with .CurrentRegion. CurrentRegion is equivalent to Ctrl+A from the currently selected cell.
Sub printRanges()

Dim tableRange As Range

' e.g. If I know that the first table column is in column C (3)
Set tableRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).CurrentRegion

Debug.Print tableRange.Address

End Sub

